# How to install Excel Services on Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise Client Access License?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a farm installation of Sharepoint 2010 Server with Enterprise Client Access License. I want to publish an excel workbook to a document library on my site, but I am unable to do so. When I go to Central Admin -> Manage Service Applications, I do not see a service application for Excel Services and its not available under the New menu there either. Kindly let me know how to install Excel Services on my Server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have SharePoint 2010 Server and not SharePoint 2010 Foundation.